# MySQL Match Against with 2 or more keywords

Tags: mysql

I have this mysql query

```
SELECT * FROM object_data WHERE MATCH(
object_data.personal_info, 
object_data.experience, 
object_data.position_preferred
) AGAINST ('Building Hotel' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

You see I have the "Building Hotel". I want to search for both `building` and `hotel` regardless of what columns they are as long as they exist both in  a row. What happens to my query is that it list all of the rows with at least 1 of those keywords.

Similar to this:

```
columnName = "Building" AND columnName = "Hotel"
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT MATCH(object_data.personal_info, object_data.experience,object_data.position_preferred) AGAINST ('Building
Hotel') as Relevance FROM object_data WHERE MATCH
('Building
Hotel') AGAINST('+Building +Hotel' IN 
BOOLEAN MODE) HAVING Relevance > 0.2 ORDER 
BY Relevance DESC
```